# Formatting Machine Learning Data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am working on getting a better understanding of how to use my own data table for a machine learning project.

my categories are:

```
[categoryname, modelitem, price, soldindays]
```

with `soldindays` being the target.

My data table has 1,200,000 rows in this format:

```
categoryname / modelitem / price / soldindays
furniture    /  chair    / 100   / 22
wood         /  table    / 79    / 4
glass        /   tv      / 190   / 9
cardboard    / desk      / 493   / 198
```

I'm not entirely sure how to reformat the data to get a good prediction. So far, I have used `K nearest neighbros` = 1, but somehow I get accuracy levels that vary between 5% and 78%.  This seems to vary greatly depending on the data I choose to train on.  I will attempt to train on all of it instead of just portions.

I formatted my data by was turning every non-numeric item into a number. I counted the unique values for every non-numeric attribute. Then I alphabetized each item in each list, and mapped each item to its ordinal position.

For example:

```
map_categorynames = [aarvarks = 1, airplanes = 2]
map_modelitems = [feet = 1, shoes = 2]
```

It came out like this:

```
categoryname / modelitem / price / soldindays
1878    /  87    / 100  / 22
197     /  290   / 79   / 4
2854    /  785   / 190  / 9
1148    /  401   / 493  / 198
```

I know i could have bad accuracy for a number of reasons, but I think that the data formatting is probably the biggest. How can I format my features numerically, and which model/set of models might be more suited for my 'type' of problem?

My first attribute, `categoryname`, has about 1000 different categories, as does `modelitem`.  `price` and `soldindays` are integers 0-10000. The output is to predict `soldindays`, to find out how long it would take a specified item to get sold given its attributes.

I've been trying my best to read and watch videos and understand it all, but there is so much variation between authors that it's hard to accumulate knowledge when it's so hard to stick with one single source of education.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PROBLEM TYPE**

Most important, note that this is a regression-type problem, not a classification.  You want to get as close as possible to the correct number of days, rather than having to get the exact answer (or lose all credit).  Your success criterion should *not* be percentage correct; rather, it should be some sort of average error percentage.  You can toss out the techniques that work with independent classification prediction.

**DATA SHAPE**

How do you know that your data contains enough information to make accurate predictions?  Usually, this discovery comes from experimenting with various ML algorithms.  Have you done any visualization on the space, or any sort of correlation, to estimate your maximum possible accuracy?

**CURRENT METHOD**

KNN is *not* good for this.  Your two string features are not properly described by placing them on a linear continuum.  The encoding you give tells us that an aardvark is *much* more closely related to an airplane than to a zebra.  You need to separate these.  As `Matthijs` already pointed out, one-hot encoding is an ideal method to separate these into orthogonal features.

Is the `modelitem` feature independent of the category?  If so, then it, too, should be one-hot encoded.  If it's dependent, a sub-type of the category, then you have a more difficult problem: keeping the secondary discriminators correlated while separating the major.  This is where a decision tree is a good tool.

**GENERAL RECOMMENDATION**

Treat this as a classic regression problem, along the lines of the canonical house pricing example from so many introductory lectures.  Explore SGD and related algorithms first.  If you don't get satisfactory results, at least you have a solid starting point, and can post again with your refined problem.

Answer (score 0):

You currently encoded your categories using a method referred to as LabelEncoding. There is a [method](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) in SKLearn which can do that for you by the way.

If you use this method for encoding and you use a model such as nearest-neighbours, you are implying that classes of your categories which are close alphabetically, are also close semantically.

For encoding categorical values for models which are not tree-based, it is much better to use [OneHotEncoding](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html). This would create a column for each of your classes filled with either ones or zeroes depending on whether that entry belongs to the class specified in the column. This could look as following:

```
Category  | is_a | is_b | is_c
A         | 1    | 0    | 0
B         | 0    | 1    | 0
```

This ensures that A is as far away from B as it is from C for your model, which should improve your results significantly.